# OctoberCMS get filePath on non images

Tags: file, upload, backend, octobercms

I'm trying to get full path of file (pdf, zip) i uploaded on backend on afterSave() call

I do get path for image files, but on any other type i'm getting null.

Any suggestion?
Thanks

Comment: We almost sure that its a bug OR deep logic which cannot be found in the documents. (

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to do something like that and when I used `getLocalPath()` Its worked with me. It should work.

Comment: For some reason its not working in AfterSave() call.
Tried couple things, but not. We think its a bug or something deep in the logic, but there is no docs for it. 
So we simply added another button on update page. once you create item (image), you redirected to update page (you start on create page first) and there we can add any function we want and call it without any problem.

Comment: Actually it's `afterSave()` and It doesn't work if you didn't code `beforeSave()` as well even if It's empty you have to put twice in your model so both can work.

Comment: not exactly. afterSave() working good even without beforeSave(), BUT its not getting path. I can do stuff in aftersave() func.